# What happens when the transaction log gets full

Tags: sql-update, sap-ase, transaction-log

What happens when the transaction log gets full during an extensive update?

does the transaction gets blocked?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the 'abort tran on log full' setting on the database.

- If it is set to true: all transactions which are open are aborted
- If it is set to false: all transactions are suspended till more space is made free

Of course threshold will trigger depending on how they are configured.

Comment: When you say suspended do the resources get freed or the tables get locked?

Answer (score -1):

First of all an event of log full depends if, at the database/device level,:

```
- the option "trunc log on checkpoint" or not  -> perhaps the transaction log never get full because of this option and if it does this could mean that one update managed to fill the entire log before a checkpoint
- you have configured sp_thresholdaction and what action this stored procedure is doing (this SP could run a truncate command).
```

If the option "abort tran on log full" is on for the specific database, the transaction will be aborted otherwise it will be blocked.

Comment: This is not a correct answer. It depends on the 'abort tran on log full' setting

Comment: @AdamLeszczyński you are correct. if also depends on this parameter. I will correct the answer.